# Failed to load resource files *.bundle.js.map on Safari only

Tags: angular, safari

In the Angular 2 application when I run it on MacOS Safari 10.0.3 I get these errors:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (main.bundle.js.map, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (polyfills.bundle.js.map, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (styles.bundle.js.map, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (vendor.bundle.js.map, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (inline.bundle.js.map, line 0)
```

All of the listed files exist in my project, also I don't get these errors on Chrome, IE11 and Firefox. I have no idea why these errors occur on Safari and they cause app to misbehave.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov Version of what?

Comment: version of You safari browser: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov It's in the first line of the post.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue. My application is Angular 2 and this only happens in safari.